# Does INSERT OVERWRITE in Hive insert by name or ordinal position?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, insert, overwrite

I am wondering how INSERT OVERWRITE in Hive works in Apache Spark. We are overwriting particular partitions only and are using the following query:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tableName1 PARTITION (col1=val1) SELECT * FROM tableName2
```

This will overwrite a specific partition and leave the others in tact. Does this write by ordinal position or by name? I can't seem to find any documentation answering this specific question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which spark version are u using ??

Comment: we are using version 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, Hive on Spark would work in the same way as Hive outside of Spark.

The chapter 5 - **HiveQL: Data manipulation** - **Inserting Data into Tables** section in [Programming Hive](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-hive/9781449326944/) book clearly states the following:

> Hive determines the values of the partition keys... , from the last
>   `<n>` columns in the SELECT clause. ... the relationship between the
>   source column values and the output partition values is by position
>   only and not by matching on names.

Hope this helps.